# convertir nombre de archivo a string c#

Tags: c#

Buen día, solicitando de su ayuda para saber como obtener el nombre de un archivo por medio de C# y guardar el nombre en una variable, es decir en una ruta determinada tengo el archivo Ejemplo1.txt, tengo que entrar a esa ruta y obtener el nombre del archivo sin declararlo previamente y después ese nombre guardarlo en una variable de tipo string.

Seria algo como esto, pero con la diferencia de que en la linea result se pasara la variable path.

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);
```

Comment: Ya tienes lo que necesitas, con la línea `result = Path.GetFileName(path);` estás obteniendo el nombre del archivo de la ruta. Este código lo sacaste de [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) y ahí se explica cómo funciona el método `GetFileName`, a menos que requieras algo diferente, en ese caso, tendrías que explicarlo en la pregunta :)

Comment: Tengo que definir la ruta a la que voy acceder, obtener el nombre de cada archivo que se encuentre dentro de esta ruta, sin definir el nombre para cada archivo y generar una lista con el nombre de cada archivo.

Comment: entonces lo que requieres es diferente a lo que preguntas. Lo que tienes que hacer es obtener todos los archvios de una carpeta con el método `GetFiles`, luego por cada iteración debes obtener el nombre del archivo con `GetFileName(nombreArchivo)` y crear una lista con todos esos nombres de archivo obtenidos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer un `Split('\')` para separar la ruta y tomar el último elemento:

```
string[] pathSplit = path.Split('\');
string name = pathSplit[pathSplit.Count - 1];
```

o podrías usar `FileInfo`:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
string name = info.Name;
```